# Kendo Grid MVC Compilation Error when loading cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, datasource

I'm getting the following error when trying to load my .cshtml file:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Source Error (Line 81):

> Line 79: .AutoBind(true)
>
> Line 80:
>
> Line 81: .DataSource(dat​asource => datasource
>
> Line 82: .Ajax()
>
> Line 83: .Model(model =>

I have tried refreshing the cache and removing elements from the grid but it is still not working.

cshtml page code:

```
@{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    var layoutId = guid + "page-layout";
    var partialModel = new Kendo_UI_Bootstrap_Integration.ViewModels.ReportLayoutViewModel();
    partialModel.Title = "Report";
    partialModel.ReportHeaderData = string.Format("<span id='{0}-start-date'>Start Date:</span><br/><span id='{0}-end-date'>End Date</span>", guid);
    partialModel.Id = layoutId;
}
@Html.Partial(MVC.Reports.Views.ViewNames._ReportLayout, partialModel)

<input id="GuidInput" type="hidden" value="@guid" />
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Start Date: </span>
                @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name(guid + "StartDate").Footer(false))
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <span>End Date: </span>
                @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name(guid + "EndDate").Footer(false))
            </td>
            @if (User.IsInRole("RearingUnitRearingManager") || User.IsInRole("BackOfficeSuperUser"))
            {
                <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
                        .Name("dropdown")
                        .DataTextField("name")
                        .DataValueField("nameguid")
                        .DataSource(dataSource =>
                        {
                            dataSource.Read(read => read.Action(MVC.ControllerName.ActionNames.Action, MVC.Controller.Name))
                            .ServerFiltering(true);
                        })

                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 306px;" })
                    )
                </td>
            }
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                @(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("Submit").Content("Submit").Events(events => events.Click("submitbutton")))
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />


    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo_UI_Bootstrap_Integration.Models.DTO.dto>()
        .Name("gridname")
        .ToolBar(tools => { tools.Pdf(); tools.Excel(); })
           .Pdf(pdf => pdf
                .AllPages()
                .AvoidLinks()
                .Landscape()
                .TemplateId(layoutId)
                .PaperSize("A4")
                .Scale(0.6)
                .RepeatHeaders()
                .Margin("7cm", "1cm", "3cm", "1cm")
                .FileName("pdf.pdf")
            )
        .Excel(excel => excel
                .AllPages(true)
                .FileName("excel.xlsx"))
        .EnableCustomBinding(true)
        .Columns(
        columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.item1).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(c => c.item2);
            columns.Bound(c => c.item3);
            columns.Bound(c => c.item4);
            columns.Bound(c => c.item5);
            columns.Bound(c => c.item6);
        }
        )
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
        .AutoBind(true)

        .DataSource(dat​asource => datasource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Field(m => m.item1).Editable(false);
            model.Field(m => m.item2).Editable(false);
            model.Field(m => m.item3).Editable(false);
            model.Field(m => m.item4).Editable(false);
            model.Field(m => m.item5).Editable(false);
            model.Field(m => m.item6).Editable(false);
        })
        .Group(group => group.Add(w => w.item1))
        .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.Controller.ActionNames.Actionname_Read, MVC.Controller.Name).Data("function"))
        .PageSize(100)
        .Batch(true)
        )
        .Events(ev => ev.PdfExport("ProcessPdf").ExcelExport("SetExcelFileName"))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "z-index: 1000; position: relative;", @class = "report-grid", report_guid = guid })
    )
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a closing bracket after the .Model bit  to close the datasource.

Comment: After the .Batch(true) I have the closing bracket for the datasource

Comment: ah yes sorry didn't see that. Where is the variable guid coming from in the `report_guid = guid`? I am assuming this is an edited version of your actual code? I have tested your code with some modifications to get it to work with one of my models successfully with minimal effort.

Comment: Yeah the code has been edited and the guid is just a Guid.NewGuid() generated at the top of the view.

Comment: I have added the entire cshtml file code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to double click the word 'datasource' it only highlighted half of the word, so I re-typed it and added a model.Id to the model definition and it worked.

I have no idea what happened here.